# Create Credential: Where is the Smart Card Certificate?

Tags: ssl, certificate

Using Edge/ IE11 (no OEMs) to login to a trusted government resource on a machine where the OP is the sole user. The requirement is to type username and password every time the site is loaded as [for some reason](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-iewindows_10/how-do-i-re-add-web-credential-in-windows-10-once/afd3edb1-41a3-4edc-9e24-e4910420492c) there is no credential record created for it.
Now to add a certificate based credential, we try:

```
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager\Add a Certificate-Based Credential
```

But it wants a smart card certificate. Never had one or a reader. But the invisible certificate is somehow classified as smart card.

Also tried the url of the resource to add a Windows Credential thus:

```
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager\Add a Windows Credential
```

But after filling in the details get:

> The information cannot be saved. Make sure the information is correct
>   and that all required fields are completed.
>   Error 0x80070057 the parameter is incorrect

On another machine, there is no need to view the same smart card certificate  <strike>as the credential record exists</strike> and the details are passed to the browser.

Can the credential be created at all?

Comment: Have you attempted to verify if the behavior exists if Edge is not used?  Are you using the native functioality or something like ActivClient?  You should update your question, please do not, reply to this comment.

Comment: It's the same with IE.

Comment: Both machines are running Windows 10?

Comment: Yes. Something happened to the record on this machine before upgrading from a previous version of Windows.

Comment: What record? You still have not indicated if your using the native functionality built into Windows 8+ or using a third-party client like ActivClient.  If you cannot be more descriptive in your responses I cannot help you.

Comment: [How to add a certificate based credential to Windows Credential Manager?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188968/how-to-add-a-certificate-based-credential-to-windows-credential-manager).  I assume when you attempted to add the certificate to the credential manager, the smart card was available, otherwise that would explain the failure.

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks, don't use any third party software. Anything else missing?

Comment: [How to add certificate to Windows Credential Manager?](https://serverfault.com/questions/579903/how-to-add-certificate-to-windows-credential-manager)

Comment: @Ramhound: Nothing in the Smart Card Trusted Root, Yet it wants one when trying to import the cert. Never had a smart card reader. Would you suggest I should contact their support?

Comment: Uhh, if the website uses a **password** and you never had a certificate, then why are you trying to add a certificate credential in the first place?

Comment: @grawity: Create Windows cred produces the error described in the OP. Maybe the other machine has the cert. It says Digicert (encrypted) on the urlbox, have they hidden it somewhere?

Comment: If you don't have a smart card reader, then how are you using a certificate, from a smart card?  Your question is really confusing.

Comment: @LaurieStearn: In this case Digicert is the issuer of the _server_ certificate. The client is _not_ using a certificate to log in – they're using username and password.

Comment: I strongly suggest you modify this question so it is clear.  It appears you are not actually using a Smart Card, one which specifically contains a certificate, used for authentication purposes.  If that is indeed the case, (i.e. you are not using a Smart Card because you are not using a Smart Card reader), then you should make that clear in your question.

Comment: Ramhound: Sorry about that. Yes. Don't know jack about any smart cards. Do you think it is used as authentication in the login process at all? 
@grawity: Hmmm, so no certificate. Great. In that case perhaps a utility is possible (AHK?) bypassing the Credential Manager to fill in the browser fields with username and password for this site. Possible?

Answer (score 0):

Having checked the "other" machine for the existence of any smart card certificates for the above mentioned site and found none, also came the epiphany that as Chrome was the default browser on that machine, [Google Passwords](https://passwords.google.com/) does not interrogate the Windows Credential DB, but has its own repository.
 
This is in tune with what grawity has suggested above, and will accordingly update this answer if there is some other way to include the logon details for the site as a *Windows* Credential, without the accompanying invalid parameter error.